# Right way to use Git? How to manage git branches?

Tags: git, github, project, git-branch

So I was doing a Project with two other peers, and we created a master and a submaster branch along with a personal branch on each of our computers. So we would pull the most recent version of our working code from the submaster and deal with conflicts locally before we try to push any changes. And we would only push submaster to master only when we have a deliverable version of our project.

I was told that having a submaster branch was the wrong way of using git and github and that I shouldn't be doing that. I always thought that committing to the master branch code that may have bugs is bad practice.

How do programmers or software engineers manage their git branches?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! From your question, it's not clear what research you've already carried out into this topic, would be interesting to know e.g. have you read https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ ?

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer to your question, only opinions. Even the names of branches can be a subject of opinion (more so these days it seems). I have main/develop as two branches in most of my own repositories, I merge to develop when I feel it is done, and I merge to master when I feel it can be released. You could take at "git flow", it is a popular way of dealing with releases and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should be branching structure is and will be question of eternity :D

So there are some standard practices that teams follows, so every team/individual should try to find out, what suits best to their work practice/work flow.

For your understanding, the branching structure that we follow,

```
Prod (master *old practice name*)
|
\
  - beta
  |
  \
   - dev
   |
   \
    - feature 1
    - feature 2
    - bug fix 1
    - bug fix 2
```

Now, here every developer/group of developers work on feature/bug branch, 
then raises Pull request to merge in dev
And it is subsequently merged up to prod branch.

Now you can device pattern that suits your team.

Only build and follow few traits.

1. Always keep code/repository clean.
2. Never allow direct pushing of commits to master/parent branches.
3. Use Pull requests to review the code, review the conflicts and then push the changes ahead.
4. Try to create new branch for every feature/bug/improvement/simply every jira or trello card.